# jQuery Using a specific UL Element for Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a website that requires the use of tabs. But the `<div>` within which I'm having my List of tabs requires another `<ul>` element with other information.

How should I force jQuery to select the second set of `<ul>` elements? Here's an example of what I want:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
      ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
        ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab.);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="tabs" class="center">
  <div class="leftpanel">
    <ul class="ignore">
      <!-- I need to ignore this <ul> -->
      <li>Some Information</li>
      <li>Some Other Information</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="Use this">
      <!-- I need this <ul> to be used instead. -->
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="center tabbed">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commod. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Aliquam nulla.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that the first unnecessary `<ul>` can't be placed elsewhere. Hence the tab functionality doesn't work.

Comment: It is hard to guess what you need without a [mcve] with for example a picture of what you expect. You could temporarily remove the first UL and insert it after the tabs are created

Comment: Wrap the `ul` you do want to target in another `div`, then target that in jQuery...?

Comment: do you want to hide first ul and use second ul in tab?

Comment: Don't understand why you can't just move the ignore ul before the div - you need to explain why it can't be moved - is there functionality based on it or is it just a styling issue?

Comment: It's actually a styling issue, The two ul's need to be at the same level since they're both on a "left panel".

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't move it; you could solve that with CSS

Comment: ok it's probably better to show that then and change your question to a css one because I don't think tabs will allow you to target a different ul, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-_getList

> Determine which list should be converted to tabs. By default the first descendant list is used.

**Example**

```
_getList: function() {
  var list = this.element.find( ".my-tabs" );
  return list.length ? list.eq( 0 ) : this._super();
}
```

For your code, this would be:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
      ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
        ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab.");
      });
    },
    _getList: function() {
      var list = this.element.find(".use-this");
      return list.length ? list.eq(0) : this._super();
    }
  });
});
```

RTFM.

**Update**

Read through the API and read through the code on GitHub:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/tabs.js

Line 491 - 494

```
// Allow overriding how to find the list for rare usage scenarios (#7715)
_getList: function() {
    return this.tablist || this.element.find( "ol, ul" ).eq( 0 );
},
```

This function should be allow override, such that code liek the following would work.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    _getList: function() {
      var list;
      this.element.find("ul").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("my-tabs")) {
          list = $(this);
        }
      });
      console.log(list);
      return list.length ? list : this._super();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="ignore">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="my-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it does not. This code appears to get ignored and the custom callback which should send *something* to the console does not.

So that is the proper method, yet it appears there is a bug.

So you can use `$.widget` to seriously override it.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.myTabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    _getList: function() {
      return this.element.find(".my-tabs");
    }
  });
  $("#tabs").myTabs();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="ignore">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="my-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code works as desired.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work, the content displays directly and the tab functionality is lost; basically the list isn't identified for some reason.

Comment: I even removed the `list.length ? <> : <>; ` checking fallback and set it to return a list of class ".hello", BUT I HAD NO such list in the HTML. 
Yet it still worked with the first list it encountered, no error was thrown. I don't think this function is ever called.

Comment: @that_brogrammer the function is called: Line 399 *this.tablist = this._getList().attr( "role", "tablist" );* And the custom callback seems to get ignored. See update.